# Taskbar Button rightclick: Customized menu in windows forms

Tags: c#, windows, winforms

I do not want the form to exit when the "close window" option is clicked in the menu that pops up when the taskbar button is right clicked. Instead, I want the application to be minimized to the  system tray. 
How do I change the behavior of the "Close Window"?

Comment: You need to have a good reason for doing this, as users tend to get annoyed when the operating system application operations don't do what they are told!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an override of `OnFormClosing` and look at the `CloseReason` of the event arguments parameter. Maybe something like this:

```
protected override OnFormClosing(FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CloseReason == CloseReason.UserClosing)
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
        this.Hide();
    }
    else
    {
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

This way, the user cannot close your form (only hide it), but Windows still can for other reasons (e.g. shutdown).

Comment: Thank you! Works like a charm. I had to change the arguments to OnFormClosing(FormClosingEventArgs e), to properly override it though.

Comment: @arhud: You are right about the signature. That would have been for an event.